# ValueError in DL

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, keras

I get this error , post choosing the epochs: ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 5516 input samples and 12870 target samples. Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance

Im using a dataset with a lot of categorical variables and they add up to 95 after creating the dummy variables, the code until I choose the number of epochs runs flawlessly and then I get this error, what is the reason for this error, its important, one, I could use it in the future and 2, Im unable to proceed :)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

dataset = pd.read_csv('zrpl_data.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, 0:6].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 6].values

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
labelencoder_X_1 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 0] = labelencoder_X_1.fit_transform(X[:, 0])

labelencoder_X_2 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 1] = labelencoder_X_2.fit_transform(X[:, 1])
labelencoder_X_3 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 2] = labelencoder_X_1.fit_transform(X[:, 2])

labelencoder_X_4 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 3] = labelencoder_X_1.fit_transform(X[:, 3])

labelencoder_X_5 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 4] = labelencoder_X_1.fit_transform(X[:, 4])

onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [0,1,2,3,4])
X = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()
X = X[:, 1:]

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.3, 
random_state = 0)

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)

import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

classifier = Sequential()

classifier.add(Dense(output_dim=47, 
init='uniform',activation='relu',input_dim=95)) 

classifier.add(Dense(output_dim=47, init='uniform',activation='relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(output_dim=1, 
init='uniform',activation='sigmoid'))

classifier.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

classifier.fit (X_train, y_train, batch_size=10,nb_epoch=100)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 5516 feature samples and 12870 target samples (you should have equal), before train the model double check their dimensions.